# How to connect SQL Server using Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps

How to connect SQL Server using Power Apps ?

How to save and retrieve data from sql server table?

Is there any reference link ?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to go Connector and create the conection to SQL Server. Then inside your Powerapps go to Data select SQL and you will see you connection alse you can create connection in this step.
Once Powerapps connected to SQL you will see the tables.

MSFT step by step tutorial --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase

Thanks to --> @ANSAR JOSEPH

On the other hand  if you are using SQL Server OnPremises you must user a Data Gateway to communicate with OnPremises and Cloud to have your hybrid.

MSFT Data Gateway tutorial --> [https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/connect-to-your-on-premises-data-sources-using-on-premises-data-gateway-from-powerapps/#:~:text=The%20data%20gateway%20can%20be,need%20to%20move%20any%20data](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/connect-to-your-on-premises-data-sources-using-on-premises-data-gateway-from-powerapps/#:%7E:text=The%20data%20gateway%20can%20be,need%20to%20move%20any%20data).

Comment: Also you need to use gateway if your SQL server is on prem

Comment: @ANSARJOSEPH Yes of course! I will edit the answer :)